# Different ways of raising a Custom Event in .NET Framework

Tags: .net, vb.net, custom-events

I know that in VB .Net it is possible to define your custom Event Handler.

This is a way for a class to know when another one is listening to its events. This example code comes from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt1k2w4e.aspx) :

```
Private Events As EventHandlerList

Public Custom Event MyEvent As EventHandler
    AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Events.AddHandler("Test", value)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler)
        Events.RemoveHandler("Test", value)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        CType(Events("Test"), EventHandler).Invoke(sender, e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

Now, this is how you can raise your custom event :

```
Private Sub MySub()
    RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

So far so good, no problem at all.

My question is, since in my class I have a direct access to the EventHandlerList, can I call it outside the custom event handler ?
And if I do, is there any difference between what this sub does from the one above ?

```
Private Sub MySub2()
    CType(Events("Test"), EventHandler).Invoke(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

I know this probably is no good habits at all, I'm just curious as I may have a function that is passed an event name as `String` so that way of raising the event might work for me, I would do something like :

```
Private Sub RaiseCustomEvent(EventName As String, Ev as EventArgs)
    CType(Events(EventName), EventHandler).Invoke(Me, Ev)
End Sub
```

Comment: That MSDN example relies on the key value (a `String`) to be [Interned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isinterned(v=vs.110).aspx).  The key argument is of type `Object` and the `EventHandlerList.Item` property uses referential equality in looking up the requested handler not the default comparer for the underlying type.  It would be better to explicitly declare a key, i.e. `Private MyEventKey As New Object`.  Also, you should be verifying that the result of `Events(EventName)` is not nothing before attempting to call `Invoke`.

Comment: Also be careful if you add a custom event to a Form class and 1) declare a new `EventHandlerList` for storing the events and 2) subsequently attach an event handler via the VS IDE that creates a method with the `Handles` clause.  Due to the way the VB compiler works, the generated code will attempt to add the eventhandler to the `EventHandlerList` before the `EventHandlerList` is instantiated.  This results in a null reference exception on the creation of the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, since in my class I have a direct access to the EventHandlerList, can I call it outside the custom event handler?

Yes.

> And if I do, is there any difference between what this sub does from the one above?

No. The RaiseEvent statement simply calls the RaiseEvent part of your event declaration. The VB.NET spec says:

> The RaiseEvent declaration takes the same parameters as the event delegate and will be called when a RaiseEvent statement is executed.

Note, though, that the MSDN example is broken---it raises a `NullReferenceException` if no event handler is attached ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k9XlCO)):

```
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim x As New T()
        x.RaiseTestEvent()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class T
    Private Events As New System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList()

    Public Custom Event MyEvent As EventHandler
        AddHandler(value As EventHandler)
            Events.AddHandler("Test", value)
        End AddHandler

        RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler)
            Events.RemoveHandler("Test", value)
        End RemoveHandler

        RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            CType(Events("Test"), EventHandler).Invoke(sender, e)
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Public Sub RaiseTestEvent()
        ' Throws NullReferenceException if no event handler is attached.
        RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub
End Class
```

For "regular" events, `RaiseEvent` is just a NO-OP if no handler is attached ([Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ctgrMV)). The VB spec says:

> The RaiseEvent statement is processed as a call to the Invoke method of the event's delegate, using the supplied parameters, if any. If the delegate’s value is Nothing, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for those precisons